# how to 'not' a lambda expression for entity framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, lambda

Given the following

```
Expression<Func<T,bool>> matchExpression;
```

How can i create another expression that is a 'not' of the existing one.

i have tried

```
Expression<Func<T, bool>> func3 = (i) => !matchExpression.Invoke(i);
```

but this is not supported by the entity framework...

Regards

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to recreate a new lambda, and negate the body of the original one:

```
Expression<Func<T, bool>> not = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>> (
    Expression.Not (matchExpression.Body),
    matchExpression.Parameters [0]);
```

Comment: (you could just pass in matchExpression.Parameters - it would be the same)

Comment: @Marc: Sure thing. But in that specific case, I like that it expresses the intent to negate the predicate with one parameter.

Comment: Also, after this question, I ended up adding a way to negate a predicate in Mono.Linq.Expressions' PredicateBuilder: http://github.com/jbevain/mono.linq.expressions So thanks Richard :)